# JavaFX: how to build fat jar without needing to specify --module-path and --add-modules during execution

Tags: java, maven, javafx, jar, fatjar

I'm sorry for this question, which has been asked many times on StackOverflow.
I wrote many GUI applications using Java Swing, but I'd like to switch to modern JavaFX.
I'm stuck on the basic problem - I cannot build a fat jar.

When I tried to run fat jar (which has 8 MB), it crashed:

```
$ java -jar app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

but if I run it with these parameters, it works:

```
$ java --module-path /usr/share/openjfx/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

It's very annoying. My previous swing applications worked without this. I played with Maven for half a day, but without success.

Can anyone please help me? I'm entirely stuck :-(

There are source files of my simple application:

`module-info.java`:

```java
module test.app {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    opens test.app to javafx.fxml;
    exports test.app;
}
```

`App.java`:

```java
package test.app;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
public class App extends Application {
    private static Scene scene;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("primary"), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }    
    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

`PrimaryController.java`:

```java
package test.app;
public class PrimaryController {   
}
```

`primary.fxml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="test.app.PrimaryController">
   <children>
      <Label text="Test" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

`pom.xml`:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>test.app.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
                            <version>11</version>
                        </dependency>        
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
                            <version>11</version>
                        </dependency>                        
                </dependencies>           
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>                         
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>test.app.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                        <id>ide-profile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Using most recent version of javafx-maven-plugin and do not use maven-assembly-plugin for that ......

Comment: "_My previous swing applications worked without this_" -- Because Swing is part of the Java standard library, but JavaFX is not. Though there are at least two vendors, BellSoft Liberica and Azul Zulu, that offer JDKs/JREs that include JavaFX in the modular run-time image.

Comment: Are you sure the JavaFX classes (and native code) are being included in your JAR file? What do you see when you inspect what's inside the JAR file?

Comment: Also, couple notes on creating an executable fat JAR file that includes JavaFX. (1) An executable JAR executed via `-jar` is placed on the class-path, but JavaFX doesn't like that. You must create a separate main class that is **not** a subclass of `Application` that simply launches the JavaFX application. You'll get a warning now, but you should be okay to ignore it. (2) The JAR file specification only supports one module per JAR file. If you're creating a fat JAR file with modular dependencies, I recommend excluding any and all `module-info.class` files (including your own).

Comment: You could use jlink to build a runtime containing JavaFX and use that with a slimmer jar of your other dependencies.

Comment: JavaFX 11 is obsolete.  I recommend using JavaFX 21 LTS instead.  If you are only using JavaFX 11 to be compatible with some pre-installed JRE, then you can instead use jlink or jpackage to include a modern JRE with your app.  The javafx-maven-plugin, that you are already using, offers support to easily build a jlink zip (though do use a recent version of the plugin and not the obsolete one you are currently using).